# Google Maps Tile URL for HYBRID mapType tiles?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have found a basic URL structure for regular map tiles:

```
https://mts1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@186112443&hl=x-local&src=app&x=1325&y=3143&z=13&s=Galile
```

What would be the URL structure to grab HYBRID map tiles from Google?

I don't know why I can't find this information; it seems like it should be easy to find.

Am I missing something simple?
.

I have been messing with the `lyrs` parameter, and I think that may be part of it.  When pasting the above URL in a browser, Ive tried `lyrs=r`, `lyrs=h`,`lyrs=t` and they give different tiles.

The closest I have come now is trying `lyrs=s`.  It results in a Satellite tile being returned; but I do not know what I should put in for a HYBRID result.

Maybe I am going about this all wrong.

Comment: "it seems like it should be easy to find.", yeah but Google is known for overcomplicating documentation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need an instance from the google map js class and an anonymous function then you can set the map object to give hybrid tiles:[How to get your image URL tiles? (google maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241268/how-to-get-your-image-url-tiles-google-maps). Or maybe it's lyrs=y

TRY: http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x=1325&y=3143&z=13

Comment: I know how to do all that; I just need the URL that grabs the HYBRID tiles.  You sent me the link where I already got the URL above.  The URL above grabs ROADMAP tiles (not satellite or hybrid).  Thanks, I do appreciate the answer.

Comment: But why? Does my answer not work? You need to set the map type.

Comment: The URL structure given in the link you sent me is `http://mt3.google.com/mapstt?zoom=13&x=1325&y=3143&client=google` this does not return a HYBRID tile.  Just paste it in your browser.

Comment: I already know how to make a HYBRID map by setting the map type, but I do not know what the URL for accessing the tile image for a HYBRID map.

Comment: Thank you!! that is just what I need.  Thanks for sticking with me; sorry I was unclear.

Answer (score 119):

For anyone who wants to save some time while looking for specific tile types:

- h = roads only
- m = standard roadmap
- p = terrain
- r = somehow altered roadmap
- s = satellite only
- t = terrain only
- y = hybrid

Comment: Is there anyone for traffic?

Comment: An addition: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/3RvxRebArfg suggests the `hl=`-parameter, which gives some options how the map is rendered (in their example, `hl=pl`, some polish standard).

Comment: I could not find any documentation for the url http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x=1325&y=3143&z=13 . May I use my authentication key with this url?

Comment: From what I could gather, the traffic layer is added as an overlay to an existing mapType. The magic string seems to be adding: "@221097413,traffic" after the mapType. So the final url might look like: https://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@221097413,traffic&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}

Comment: thanks to @pkExec Also you can use "@221097413,transit" to add Transit on map. Don't know if is possible to get bicycling someway or not .

Comment: Where did you even find this? I have been looking for while

Comment: Does anyone know a tileserver with zoom level up to 22 or 23?

Comment: @AliNGame It is possible, add 'bike'. Thanks for the transit tip.

Comment: @JaffaKetchup as I mentioned in my comment before, I don't know. If you find any way to add bicycling please let me know too. Thank you

Comment: @AliNGame I said IT IS POSSIBLE. Add 'bike' like you add 'traffic'. Example: '@221097413,bike'

Comment: @JaffaKetchup oh I didn't know that. thanks for the information.

Comment: what about the photogrammetric url?

Answer (score 16):

Hybrid Maps URL:

```
http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga
```

Comment: what is the difference between `mt0` and `mt1` and `mts1` ?

Comment: @Douglas.Sesar Google uses four different servers to balance the load. These are mt0, mt1, mt2 and mt3. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14793/How-Google-Map-Works

Comment: @Douglas.Sesar: Smart clients were supposed to spread the load across servers mt0 to mt3.
But now, these names and mt are all aliases (CNAMEs) of mt.l.google.com that the DNS rotates through a number of addresses as it is queried.  So, simply using mt.google.com will do the balancing globally, and locally if you do multiple DNS queries.

Comment: Does this need an API Key?

Comment: @LoMaPh no, no API Key needed in this case.

Comment: What is the "s=GA" parameter for?

Comment: @heltonbiker I'm not sure but it can be excluded, as can the ```hl``` parameter, just to make it concise.

Answer (score 1):

Probably off topic, but I was facing an issue with the HTTP protocol (tiles weren't showing up), so if you see nothing, then consider using your preferred tiles with HTTPS.

Answer (score -7):

The truth is: there is no URL specifically that holds both satellite and street info like you see in google maps hybrid. You have to combine them. Here's an example:

https://github.com/SnakeO/mapbox-with-google-maps-hybrid-tiles

Comment: That is not the truth; the accepted answer gives the lyrs parameter to be "y" ( which give the HYBRID tiles as requested )