# How to get traffic in Google map image

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

An image of Google Map ***without traffic*** can be obtained by following code:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request

url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-30.027489,-51.229248&size=800x800&zoom=22&sensor=true"

buffer = BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
image = Image.open(buffer)
image.save("Map.png")
```

This code is not providing any information about traffic. Can I change above `url` i.e. ***http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-30.027489,-51.229248&size=800x800&zoom=22&sensor=true*** to get traffic data? I know that traffic data can be obtained by:

[Google Maps Tile URL for HYBRID mapType tiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017766/google-maps-tile-url-for-hybrid-maptype-tiles)

But is there a way to change `url` so that traffic lines can be obtained?

Answer (score 1):

The [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide) doesn't support traffic.  If you have a source of traffic data (and the appropriate data for the roads, you can overlay colored polylines on a static map; but Google doesn't support it (at the present time).